# Python3 parse xml

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I tried to parse XML using different python3 modules and different articles from internet but not success.

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:cwmp="urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">

<cwmp:GetParameterValuesResponse>
    <ParameterList SOAP-ENC:arrayType="cwmp:ParameterValueStruct[3]">
        <ParameterValueStruct>
            <Name>SOME_NAME_1_HERE</Name>
            <Value>2</Value>
        </ParameterValueStruct>
        <ParameterValueStruct>
            <Name>SOME_NAME_2_HERE</Name>
            <Value>180</Value>
        </ParameterValueStruct>
        <ParameterValueStruct>
            <Name>SOME_NAME_3_HERE</Name>
            <Value>1800</Value>
        </ParameterValueStruct>
    </ParameterList>
</cwmp:GetParameterValuesResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I need to take data from XML tags: Name and Value
It should be something like:

```
SOME_NAME_1_HERE 2
SOME_NAME_2_HERE 180
SOME_NAME_3_HERE 1800
```

How I can get this values using Python3(will be good to use python default modules - not bs4)?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `xml.etree` you can execute simple XPath expression `.//element_name` to find element anywhere within a given context element :

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('path_to_your_xml.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for p in root.findall('.//ParameterValueStruct'):
    print("%s | %s" % (p.find('Name').text, p.find('Value').text))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code works. But with some changes in PRINT.

Comment: Just spent a while solving an issue where this answer wasn't working for some reason. Turns out that `findall()` will be affected by your element's `xmlns` attribute. So make sure you have a valid `xmlns` attribute on your element if this doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('Newfile.xml').getroot()

print(e)
for atype in e.findall('.//ParameterValueStruct'):
    print("%s | %s" % (atype.find('Name').text, atype.find('Value').text))
```

Comment: Thanks, but your code print nothing.

`/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/ppikh/Desktop/test.py

Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: `e.findall('.//ParameterValueStruct')`

Comment: @har07 In your case I received: None for each print

Comment: @PetroPikh `get()` supposed to be used for reading XML attribute. Use `find()` instead to get single XML element, and then get the element's inner text from `text` property. See the other answer..