# How can we parse xml data that contains nodes with xml namespace tags in python?

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am getting XML as a response so I want to parse it. I tried many python libraries but not get my desired results. So if you can help, it will be really appreciative.

The following code returns `None`:

```
xmlResponse = ET.fromstring(context.response_document)
a = xmlResponse.findall('.//Body')
print(a)
```

Sample XML Data:

```
<S:Envelope
       xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
       <S:Header>
           <wsa:Action s:mustUnderstand="1"
               xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
               xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:ihe:iti:2007:RegistryStoredQueryResponse
           </wsa:Action>
       </S:Header>
       <S:Body>
           <query:AdhocQueryResponse status="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:ResponseStatusType:Success"
               xmlns:query="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:3.0">
               <rim:RegistryObjectList
                   xmlns:rim="u`enter code here`rn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0"/>
               </query:AdhocQueryResponse>
           </S:Body>
       </S:Envelope>
```

I want to get status from it which is in Body. If you can suggest some changes of some library then please help me. Thanks

Comment: You can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589769/python3-parse-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following base code:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
```

Let's build on top of it to get your desired output.

Your initial find for `.//Body` x-path returns NONE because it doesn't exist in your XML response.

Each tag in your XML has a **namespace** associated with it. More info on xml namespaces can be found [here](https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/learn-xml-schema/namespaces.cfm).

Consider the following line with `xmlns` value (xml-namespace):

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
```

The value of namespace `S` is set to be `http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope`.

Replacing `S` in `{S}Envelope` with value set above will give you the resulting tag to find in your XML:

```py
root.find('{http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Envelope') #top most node
```

We would need to do the same for `<S:Body>`.

---

To get`<S:Body>` elements and it's child nodes you can do the following:

```py
body_node = root.find('{http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Body')

for response_child_node in list(body_node):
  print(response_child_node.tag) #tag of the child node
  print(response_child_node.get('status')) #the status you're looking for
```

Outputs:

```sh
{urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:3.0}AdhocQueryResponse
urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:ResponseStatusType:Success
```

---

**Alternatively**

You can also directly **find all** `{query}AdhocQueryResponse` in your XML using:

```py
response_nodes = root.findall('.//{urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:3.0}AdhocQueryResponse')

for response in response_nodes:
  print(response.get('status'))
```

Outputs:

```sh
urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:ResponseStatusType:Success
```